# NameError in Python when opening - don't know why

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, nameerror

I have used this code but don't understand why it doesn't work (on Jupyterlabs 3.8)- error that comes us up is shown below.

```py
import pandas as pd

pwd

'/Users/hassanmazhar/Desktop/Data Analytics course'

journal=pd.read('/Users/hassanmazhar/Desktop/Data Analytics course/Journals.csv')

journal.head()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a1ac9a5c147f> in <module>
----> 1 journal.head()

NameError: name 'journal' is not defined
```

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem but you should use `pd.read_csv`

Comment: I guess you need to enter a correct path. Like `C://Users/hassanmazhar/Desktop/Data Analytics course/Journals.csv`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try re-running all the cells again

Comment: Make sure that the cell that defines `journal=...` ran correctly and without any errors.

Comment: Great thanks all, the key to make it work was adding a r before the file path, but could not understand why...

Answer (score 0):

You should try using pd.read_csv and also add an r before your file path.

Comment: Thanks! When using the r it worked :) do you know why? the exact same code without the r did not work